# How to modify tooltip of Horizontal Multi-Bar Chart NVD3

Tags: jquery, nvd3.js

Is it possible that the tool tip of the second data can be modify in Horizontal Multi-Bar?.

For example the tool tip of the bluer data and the light blue must have a separate tool tip.

[image]

here is my nvd3 code.

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart()
        .x(function(d) { return d.label })
        .y(function(d) { return d.value })
      //  .yDomain([0, parseFloat(maxY)])
        .margin({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 175})
        .showValues(false)           //Show bar value next to each bar.
        .showControls(false);        //Allow user to switch between "Grouped" and "Stacked" mode.


    d3.select('#bar_chart svg')
        .datum(sample_json())
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
});
```

and this is my sample json

```
function sample_json(){
var data = [
  {
    "key": "Example A",
    "color": "#4f99b4",
    "values": [
      {
        "label" : "200000200000000" ,
        "value" : 2.8082472075876
      } , 
      {
        "label" : "200000200000000" ,
        "value" : 3.8082472075876
      } 
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Example B",
    "color": "#ff7f0e",
    "values": [
      {
        "label" : "200000200000000" ,
        "value" : 3.8082472075876
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Example C",
    "color": "#aec7e8",
    "values": [
      {
        "label" : "200000200000000" ,
        "value" : 8.8082472075876
      } 
    ]
  }
]

return data;
}
```

i have tried .tooltip and have some function but it doesn't work..
TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it. You can use the tooltip and tooltipContent attributes and then check the serie with an if else or switch statement.

```
var chart = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart()
    .x(function(d) { return d.label })
    .y(function(d) { return d.value })
  //  .yDomain([0, parseFloat(maxY)])
    .margin({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 175})
    .showValues(false)           //Show bar value next to each bar.
    .showControls(false)
    .tooltips(true)
    .tooltipContent(function(key, y, e, graph) {
      var tooltip_content = '';
      if(key == 'Example A'){
        tooltip_content = '';//tooltip content here
      }else if (key == 'Example B'){
        tooltip_content = '';//tooltip content here
      }else if (key == 'Example C'){
        tooltip_content = '';//tooltip content here
      }
      return tooltip_content;
    });
```

Comment: im sorry but .tooltips and _.tooltipContent_ is deprecated in 1.8+, i've used _.tooltip.contentGenrator,_ and i thank you for thatm, but still, i cant get the value of `{ "label":"200000200000000","value" : 2.8082472075876}` which its the bluer bar. and the `{ "label":"200000200000000","value" : 3.8082472075876}` is the light blue bar of _Example A_ data i want those have a separate tooltips when hover.. but still thanks for the code.